# Faster multiplication of two polynomials over a field

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, arithmetic

Let $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ are given two monic polynomials each of degree $i$.  I want to compute the product of these two polynomials (i.e.) the coefficients of resulting polynomials. Here  operations will field operations like addition and multiplication etc.

**Brute force Algorithm :** Just as usual multiply the coefficients, computing the one coefficient of resulting polynomial will take $i+1$ many multiplications and addition of two degree $i$ polynomials takes $i+1$ operations. I will adding $i$ times, so overall operations are $i \times (i+1)$ +$(i+1)\times i$.

> Questions : Is it possible to in $i^2 -2i +1$ many operations? please explain

Comment: I don’t uderstand from where we have to add $i$ times and overall operations are $i \times (i+1)$ +$(i+1)\times i$. Let $f=f_0+f_1x+\dots+f_{i-1}x^{i-1}+x^i$ and $g(x)=g_0+x$. Let $fg=h=h_0+h_1x+\dots+ h_{i}x^i+x^{i+1}$.
Then $h_0=f_0g_0$ and $h_{j}=f_{j-1}+f_{j}g_0$ for $1\le j\le i$.  Thus we need $i+1$ multiplications and $i$ additions.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should actually post a new question. Editing an existing question to change what it asks -- especially in a way that invalidates existing answers -- is not the way to ask your new question.

Comment: @Hurkyl what specific problem are you trying to solve? "especially in a way that invalidates existing answers" but it seems to me that in this case  there was none? Your answer was given days after the edit was made. The only thing there was is a comment by Alex that referred to the version that was bountyed. You just invalidated that comment (and OPs self-answer).

Comment: There are competing versions of the question, and the situation is not really coherent. Either clarify the question once and for all, making your question and your attempt in the question match or let's forget about this entire thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $I$ and let $g$ be a polynomial of degree . So product $fg$ needs $i-1$ multiplications and $i-1$ many additions, so to $i^2 - 2i +1$ many operations required.

Answer (score 1):

Methods like [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) can compute products using a smaller operation count. As the degree gets large, methods based on Fourier transforms can achieve rather small operation counts, almost linear in $i$.

Operation counts for polynomial multiplication algorithms usually only count how many multiply operations you do, for two reasons:

- Multiplying scalars is often slower than adding them
- Usually the number of additions is proportional to the number of multiplications, so you can infer the total operation count just from the multiplies.